# How to change the default theme in telerik wpf

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-window

My project is used `telerik wpf`, I want to change default theme,

I read http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radwindow-how-to-change-the-default-theme.html
already but it didn't help me resolve the issue because this document guide how to change theme for RadWindow. it isn't for all windows and pages.
In a project, we have many pages and windows, so "default theme" means the theme is applied for all pages and window. now, I must change theme for each `radcontrol` in page or window by the way using like this: `<telerik:RadGridView telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Vista" ....`

anyone can help me?
thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Like typing words into Google and stuff? Searching [Telerik docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/common-styling-apperance-setting-theme.html) maybe?

Comment: I tried my best, and cannot find out solution.
Please read my question again, my project is wpf, it isn't silverlight

Comment: If you need to change theme for the whole application then why do you read docs for RadWindow? You gotta learn how to search docs, man. See [this link](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/common-styling-apperance-setting-theme-wpf.html#Setting_Application-Wide_Built-In_Theme_in_the_Code-Behind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find down solution: Declare the following code before the InitializeComponent() at MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new VistaTheme();
```

Answer (score 0):

To Improve the Answer of [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3654898/john-nguyen) ! John Nguyen.
We must set the IsWindowsThemeEnabled property to false if you use the RadRibbonWindow as main windows of your application.